# On Microsoft Uno Platform, how to get user confirmation when 'Close' button is clicked?

Tags: c#, .net, uno

I am trying out Uno Platform for a desktop application. I want it to work on Linux also. I would like to know how get confirmation from the user when he clicks the 'Close' button of the Window in which the app runs. I have succeeded in creating multiple pages for the app and I now know how to navigate between them. But I couldn't find a way to prevent the user from accidently closing the app by clicking the 'Close' button.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Well, my question does not relate to any error in my code.  My programming experience relates to WinForms in C#.  In WinForms, in order to prevent a user of my application from closing the main windows and loose the data, I can add code for the 'OnClose' event to get a confirmation. But in Uno, I couldn't find any such event. So, my question is, what is the solution for this problem ?